# Fastlane match with multiple existing apps in a corporate environment

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm having trouble with the basic understanding of iOS app signing and getting these apps ready for `testflight` and `deployment` using `Fastlane`.

I've been to tasked to automate the deployment steps of apps we have and we have an `Ionic Cordova` setup currently that was used to build iOS and Android projects for 18 different apps that are currently on the app store, but I'm looking to streamline the whole process using Fastlane and I'm stumped at the `Certification` stages of the process.

I've no access to the existing apps private keys or know how to go about setting up the project using Fastlane as I keep receiving the errors shown below.

I've tried to follow the concepts on [Fastlane Codesigning concepts](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/), using the Fastlane projects (cert, sigh and match) and following https://codesigning.guide/ while still making no progress.

---

*How can I go about setting up the certs on the Mac to enable it to build and push the apps to Testflight and pushing the apps fundamentally to the app store?*

Thank you

---

**Errors Recieved**

> Could not create another Distribution certificate, reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates.
>
> Could not find the newly generated certificate installed fastlane
>
> Security find-identity -v -p codesigning return 0 valid identities found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have existing distribution certificates, you will have to revoke them via the developer portal or automatically via fast lane with:

```
fastlane match nuke distribution
```

BE WARNED: this will remove all certificates and provisioning profiles for distribution (development or enterprise is unaffected). Apps that are already released to the App Store and ready for sale are UNAFFECTED, this only affects packages you sign for the App Store and submit with OLD certificates, but since you have no access to them you are fine anyway.

fast lane can then create its own when you invoke it (its fairly automated).

Comment: Could you recommend any tutorials that can help me? Or a more in-depth approach to my problem. I've already gone down that route for development, but still found problems with the error messages I received? I can try the distribution certificates tomorrow but this problem has taken me 2 days to complete and I'm unsure of my next plan of action. Thank you.

Comment: The documentation is pretty good. If you let fast lane handle the certificate signing. Also make sure you run keychain unlock if signed in over SSH. Typically you use fast lane more often for distribution than development, and so I recommend you to nuke your distribution and let it sign a new set.

Comment: How do I go about `Next, create a new private key and certificate for each environment, such as “Distribution” and “Development”. Then store these private keys and certificates in your Git repo.`?

Comment: The idea of it is that match will do this for you. Run the mentioned nuke command and then run `fastlane match`

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot thinking them steps had to be completed before running Match. Do you know how I would fix `There are no local code signing identities found. You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.`. I've removed every login cert except the WWDCA cert

Comment: Make sure the user it uses has permissions to create and approve CSR for development/distribution.

Comment: The user is the admin user on the Apple Developer Portal. I'm not sure whether that's what you mean?

Comment: Should be fine then. Are you doing it locally or on SSH? and at what step does that error come?

Comment: I actually solved this by creating provisioning profiles on the developer center

Comment: Weird. Kind of defeats the purpose of fast lane... at least it works

Comment: Is there a way how to reuse an existing distribution certificate? Why the old certificate has to be nuked and a new one created?

Comment: You may be able to coerce it through the command line, however the thing is, you shouldn't worry about managing it - fast lane handles that for you with sigh/match. In theory you don't care what the certificate is or care what it is called. If you don't have any pending apps, it is safe to nuke and fast lane will automatically update as needed.